Reading table elements from Word with python, is it possible?
So basically I have this ms-word file, its a word list, and I want a python program to it which reads the elements by rows, I mean like first row, reads english(first column) then reads hungarian(second column) then it goes to the next row and so on. But I want to make it like when I start the program I need to type in like "From:" e.g. 1A "To:" e.g. 1C.
I want those words to be typed after it reads it(I have a code for a dumber version of this, it reads the text from a txt file then it reformats it then writes it into the desired website).
It looks like this:
import keyboard
import time
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
import re


def remove_brackets(text):
    pattern = r'\[.*?\]'
    return re.sub(pattern, '', text)


def transform_text(english_input_file, english_output_file):
    with open(english_input_file, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read()
    cleaned_text = remove_brackets(text)
    lines = cleaned_text.split('\n')
    transformed_text = ';'.join([line.strip() for line in lines])
    with open(english_output_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(transformed_text)


english_input_file = 'english_input_file.txt'
english_output_file = 'english_output_file.txt'
transform_text(english_input_file, english_output_file)


def transform_text(hungarian_input_file, hungarian_output_file):
    with open(hungarian_input_file, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read()
    cleaned_text = remove_brackets(text)
    lines = cleaned_text.split('\n')
    transformed_text = ';'.join([line.strip() for line in lines])
    with open(hungarian_output_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(transformed_text)


hungarian_input_file = 'hungarian_input_file.txt'
hungarian_output_file = 'hungarian_output_file.txt'
transform_text(hungarian_input_file, hungarian_output_file)

# giving title
title = ""


def save_title():
    global title
    title = entry.get()
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Study Set Title")
window_width = 400
window_height = 200
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_coordinate = (screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (window_width, window_height, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
label = tk.Label(root, text="Title:", font=("Helvetica", 14))
label.pack(pady=10)
entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 12))
entry.pack(pady=10)
entry.focus_set()
entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: save_title())
root.mainloop()

webbrowser.open('https://quizlet.com/create-set')
time.sleep(5)
# discarding the draft
pyautogui.click(460, 910)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(1080, 220)
time.sleep(3)
# giving title and goes to write the cards
pyautogui.click(650, 460)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.write(title)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(270, 980)

# reading words
with open("english_output_file.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as english_file, open("hungarian_output_file.txt", "r",
                                                                               encoding="UTF-8") as magyar_file:
    english_lines = english_file.read().split(";")
    magyar_lines = magyar_file.read().split(";")

# accents
accented_characters = {
    'á': "\u00E1",
    'é': "\u00E9",
    'í': "\u00ED",
    'ó': "\u00F3",
    'ö': "\u00F6",
    'ő': "\u0151",
    'ú': "\u00FA",
    'ü': "\u00FC",
    'ű': "\u0171"
}

# writing the cards
for english_line, magyar_line in zip(english_lines, magyar_lines):
    keyboard.write(english_line.strip())
    keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
    magyar_line = magyar_line.strip()
    for char in magyar_line:
        if char in accented_characters:
            keyboard.press_and_release(accented_characters[char])
        else:
            keyboard.write(char)
    keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
    time.sleep(7)

# save
pyautogui.click(1640, 200)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(1530, 350)

